# How would i build a banner ad into my iOS application using RevMob?

Tags: ios, revmob

I'm new to implementing ads to my app, how would i go about building a banner ad right into one of the view controllers on my app?

Comment: Why hasn't the revmob API not worked for you? Have you even tried this? Sign up to revmob and you get all the instruction you want to do this. Its that simple.

Comment: it only shows me how to activate the ad using a button, how would i set the ad to load automatically?

Comment: Then you are looking at the wrong place. Look at http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios.html

Comment: thats where i was looking, it doesn't load a banner for me, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Well in that case let me tell you that sometimes, although you've done everything right, revmob won't load up. I have seen this behaviour myself. It would help if you could post some code to show us what you have implemented for revmob. For example, right now, we don't know IF you have tried anything or have tried everything and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
[[RevMobAds session]showBanner];
```

Do not forget to import the framework:

```
#import <RevMobAds/RevMobAds.h>
```

You could also found the answer here: http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/ios.html#banner
This link gives the code AND a video to show you how. What more do you need?

Comment: I think its much better to point the OP to the resource to solve the problem, rather than spoon feeding the answer.

Comment: I'm just confused because in the video it shows how to set up buttons that activate and de activate the ads

Comment: @user2918086 Post the code above in my answer in `viewDidLoad` for the viewcontroller you want to put the banner in.

Comment: ok thanks so much, i was finally able to understand what to do.  thanks guys!

Comment: @user2918086 You welcome. Please do not forget the check. It is the tick next to this post.